# zabbix monitoring mysql database

Tags: linux, zabbix

I have a server running multiple instances of mysql and also has the zabbix-agent running.

In zabbix_agentd.conf i have specified:

```
UserParameter=multi.mysql[*],mysqladmin --socket=$1  -uzabbixagent extended-status 2>/dev/null | awk '/ $3 /{print $$4}'
```

where $1 is the socket instance.

From the zabbix server i can run the test successfully.

```
zabbix_get -s ip_of_server  -k multi.mysql[/var/lib/mysql/mysql2.sock]
```

and it returns all the values

However the zabbix item/trigger does not generate the graphs, I have created a MACRO for $1 which is the socket location

```
{$MYSQL_SOCKET1} = '/var/lib/mysql/mysql2.sock'
```

and i use this key in items to poll the value

```
multi.mysql[{$MYSQL_SOCKET1},Bytes_sent]
```

**LOGS:**

this is what i get on the logs:

```
3360:20120214:144716.278 item [multi.mysql['/var/lib/mysql/mysql2.sock',Bytes_received]] error: Special characters '\'"`*?[]{}~$!&;()<>|#@' are not allowed in the parameters
  3360:20120214:144716.372 item [multi.mysql['/var/lib/mysql/mysql2.sock',Bytes_sent]] error: Special characters '\'"`*?[]{}~$!&;()<>|#@' are not allowed in the parameters
```

Any ideas where the problem could be?

FIXED

```
{$MYSQL_SOCKET1} = /var/lib/mysql/mysql2.sock
```

i removed the single quotes from the line and it worked...

Comment: Can you post that as an answer and accept it, so that the question doesn't show up in the unanswered list?

Answer (score 1):

FIXED

```
{$MYSQL_SOCKET1} = /var/lib/mysql/mysql2.sock
```

i removed the single quotes from the line and it worked...